# Guava cache memory leak

Tags: java, guava

I am using guava library 14.0.1 to implement caching service (a web application containing a servlet to put and get values). The web application is deployed on a machine containing 1GB RAM (google backend). The number of write and read operations is huge (50 queries per second).

The amount of RAM used on the machine keeps on increasing even after hitting the maximumSize limit. I suspect memory leak.

Following is the code I am using to create cache

```
Cache cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .initialCapacity(2000000)
                .maximumSize(3800000)
                .concurrencyLevel(50)
                .recordStats()
                .build();
```

Retrieving the values using

```
Map result = cache.getAllPresent(keys);
```

Putting values in the cache using

```
cache.put(key, value);
```

Is there anything setting that I can use to stop increase in RAM usage beyond the limit.

Comment: Have you opened a ticket on the guava project page?
[https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/list](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/list)

Comment: Just now created a new issue.

Answer (score 4):

The query rate is pretty low, so I would try reducing the concurrency (possibly 1-4) and reducing the maximum size.  Given the limited resources of your machine, I suspect a maximum size of 1K to 100K is more appropriate depending on how large your objects are.

From the Java docs

> public CacheBuilder maximumSize(long size)
>   Specifies the maximum number of entries the cache may contain.

If your entries are say 1 KB, you would need about 4 GB for this cache alone.

The reason I say the rate is pretty low is that a call to this collection should typically take a micro-second (i.e. your limit is likely to be in the order of one million per second, for a concurrency of 1)

Comment: Size is not an issue. I am storing Long's. When I hit the maximumSize specified the amount of RAM consumed is 950MB. But it doesn't stop there. It keeps on increasing.

Comment: @Rakesh The maximumSize is not absolute, as the clean-up is amortized (from the javadoc: "If maximumSize or maximumWeight is requested entries **may** be evicted on each cache modification"; emphasis mine). That's why you can actually have more entries than the maximum specified, and why you don't want a concurrency level too high as Peter suggested since that creates as many segments in the `Cache`, segments across which the maximum size has to be somewhat enforced. A concurrency level of 50 for 50 requests/s isn't necessary.